# How to remove spaces from field names when importing external data into MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an external file that I don't create which I need to import on a rolling basis, most of the column headers/field names have spaces in them. Is there a query I can write to change all of them at once? I'd rather not write a long query to get rid of spaces for each individual field name. The field names are always the same and in the same order in the file, the spaces are in the middle of the field names (ex: "Employee Number").

Comment: Why do you need to remove spaces? Just enclose names with square brackets or backticks in queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, "query" refers to an SQL statement (including those viewed in Design View) that *retrieve or act on data already in the database*.  Importing data from an external file is a separate action, not generally called a query.  So strictly speaking the answer is "no".

However, Access does have built-in import functionality in Access.  I suppose you can call these import "functions" or "actions" or "processes", just not queries. And **I'm not being a smart aleck**, since much of getting help with applications and code is learning and using the correct terms.

- Go to the External Data ribbon (a.k.a. toolbar) along the top of Access.
- Click the Import Text File icon (careful not to click the *Export* Text File icon, since they look similar. Hover the mouse cursor over each button to see the text description of it).
- Choose the filename, and pick which import option

  - As Gustav instructs in his answer, choosing "Link to data source by creating a linked table" is the most efficient solution for external files that don't change format.  The linked table (hence the external file) can be re-queried without repeating numerous steps.
- Walk through the Import Wizard steps.  Play with the options if you need to figure it all out.

  - In particular, make sure to **check "First Row Contains Field Names"**
  - **On one of the wizard steps, you can edit the field names to remove the spaces.**
- On the last step, click the "Save Import Steps" checkbox, specify a name, then click the "Save Import" button

To re-use the previously-saved import steps:

- Go to the External Data ribbon (a.k.a. toolbar) along the top of Access.
- Click "Saved Imports" button
- Choose your saved import settings
- Click Run

OR if you created a Linked table

- There is no need to "re-import".  Instead, a normal Access query can be used to get the data and update one of your normal data tables.
- If the path of the external files changes, this can also be updated by right-clicking the linked table and choosing Linked Table Manager (also available on the External Data ribbon). Select the table in the list and also check "Always prompt for new location" before clicking OK.  A standard file selection dialogue will be shown for selecting a new filepath.

(Just to be complete, it is also possible to write VBA code in Access to open a file, read and analyze the headers and then import the data according to your custom behavior, but this isn't for you if you'd "rather not write a long..." something to do this.)

Comment: In commenting on Gustav's answer, I realized that I also assumed the external file was a text file without knowing for sure.  Until the OP gives more details, my answer may or may not be relevant, but if it is a different format, similar options exist in renaming field names for other import formats.

Comment: Well, it is just as relevant or irrelevant as my solution - indeed it requires the same or even more work, so please don't downvote other solutions when you have no better solution on hand.

Comment: Indeed, I felt obliged to comment since I realized I had also assumed various details and so I admitted my blunder. And yes, now I see that the first set of steps I included are essentially identical to setting up a linked table using the same parameters... including renaming (aliasing) the fields. I do not downvote lightly, but even if your personal knowledge and the idea of your answer is just as good, your actual typed answer was very sparse on details. The fact that the user was asking about this in first place indicated that more than a command to "do it this way" was appropriate.

Comment: thank you @CPerkins, I am still new to Access and this helped a lot, I forgot all the import setup you can do.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd rather not write a long query to get rid of spaces for each individual field name.

Maybe not, but there is no smart way to overcome this.

However, don't import the file but *link* it. Then use the linked file as source in your query. In this, alias the field names as you prefer, and do basic filtering and conversion of data. Then use this query for your further processing.

Comment: -1 Because the first comment is just that --a comment-- and doesn't need an answer.  Whether or not a data-source is linked does not answer the primary question about removing spaces from field names. I think that the question is not very well formed, but there is no need to second-guess the poster's requirement by suggesting linking and field-name aliasing.  It is especially unhelpful when he shared no details of the external file format, so linking directly to the external file may be completely impractical.

Comment: Linking the file - text or Excel or whatever - is a proven solution, easy to carry out, easy to maintain. Additionally, using a query this way, brings you at no extra cost the possibility to include first level filtering (invalid or null data) and/or basic conversion (text dates to true dates, etc.), so - sorry - your downvote is offending me.

Comment: No need to be offended. I think the point to adding an explanation for down votes (stackoverflow prompted me to do so) is to continue the dialog.  I'll admit that I learned something myself by exploring the link further and so I'll take your comments as an addition to your answer.  But before you posted those comments, your answer seemed to assume much without explanation. Even if you personally are very knowledgeable and knew this works well, your answer was rather commanding "don't import the file..." instead of explanatory and enlightening.

Comment: OK, but - really - you don't import the file but link it, then use the query to import the data. Indeed, if you are not that experienced, it is much easier to tweak and repeat the process using the query GUI designer, than running multiple steps where you adjust the import specifications which often still requires a query to tweak the data before appending the target table.

Comment: I don't disagree, and now I see the link is much better for cases that the imported file format never changes. My instructions where also meant to avoid many repeated steps, hence my suggestion to save the steps for reuse without much effort... and the generated import table would be used similarly to the linked query.  (I've learned something--next time I'll comment and wait before downvoting an answer. As I said, I rarely downvote and I've never needed to reconsider that before. If you edit, I'll upvote since it won't let me now.)

Comment: That's very kind of you. But you explained yourself very well, so let's leave it as it is - as an example that you often will have different routes offered to accomplish a task. Which to choose depends on so many things where - in questions like this - most are left out for clarity.